# Storing / Caching User's location for a Performance boost

Tags: cache, cookie, ups, ad

I have multiple widgets and Visual Web Parts that querys a 'User Settings' list for their location and if that returns null, I check the User Profile Service (=AD) for the location. Rather than do both of these operations ~6 times every page load, I would like to cache their location for a performance boost.

My question is, what is the best way to cache this location variable? Is Distributed cache overkill? How about a simple Session variable? A Cookie? Server Cache? Viewstate? Any suggestions for the quickest read per user would be helpful.

Comment: Local storage could work too.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Does local mean on the client or the server?

Comment: On/in the client browser, http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-web-storage/

Comment: Very cool! I guess this wouldn't be supported in IE8 eh?

Comment: Actually, I just read that it is supported in IE 8! The only problem being my operations are written in C#, this is all javascript. How do I mesh them together?

Comment: there is a helpful JS library called store.js that helps abstract away some of the complexities, https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for local variables with respect to code , go for sessions.

- dispose all objects
- implement best practise for caml query to load splist and doc lib.

Use SpMonitor and see the performance results in developer dashboard.

If you still face issue with performance , then see if disributed cache suits your farm or no .

Comment: Atm, I dispose everything and implement the best CAML possible, but that doesn't help with the caching question. Trying to enable dev dashboard through stsadm and having some issues.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing entirely how your page functions and how the widgets work, another option would be to store it using the [local storage](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-web-storage/) capabilities of the browser. I have used this in cases to store user locations, list names, and other things so they don't have to be repeatedly fetched from the UPS or other sources.

There is a JS library called [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/) that really helps make using local storage dead simple.

The caveat here though it is tied to the browser the user uses. So If I use Chrome today, I'll see the speed gains after the initial page load. If I switch over to IE, it has to repull the information from the source to then store it in IE.

Comment: This sounds like a great technique, unfortunately, all of my widgets are written using the Object model / c#. I cannot rewrite them all to use javascript. I would like to stay in code behind while reading / writing to the cache

Comment: understood, it least now you're aware of it and can maybe take advantage of it in the future :-)